# Should I place "sometimes" and "might" in a single sentence?

Tags: adverbs, modal-verbs

Should I place "sometimes" and "might" in a single sentence?

For example, the sentence "Sometimes it might be true." is correct but seems redundant.

A. "Sometimes it might be true."

B. "Sometimes it's true."

C. "It might be true."

When would it be better to use A, B and C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of 'sometimes ... might' is never grammatically incorrect, but it does imply that there are times when the condition is always untrue. If I said **"Looking at the sky sometimes you might see clouds"** then the *sometimes* can be said to be redundant because (in the UK at any rate) there are relatively few times when the sky is truly cloudless.

But if I said **"Looking at the sky when it is raining sometimes you might see a rainbow"** then the *sometimes* is not redundant because (again in the UK) rainbows appear comparatively rarely compared to the the total number of times when rain is falling.

Most of the time when rain is falling it is impossible to see a rainbow because the sun is obscured by cloud, it is night, or the sun is in the wrong position relative to you and the shower of rain to produce a rainbow you can see. Furthermore, even if there is a rainbow you can see, you would not see it if you were looking in the wrong direction or it was hidden by buildings or trees.

Using 'sometimes' in the second example indicates that there are times when it is raining and seeing a rainbow is possible, but that there are other times when it is raining and seeing a rainbow is impossible. Using 'might' in the same sentence indicates that, even if it is possible, you are not certain to see one. In this case, and others like it, neither 'sometimes' nor 'might' is redundant.